# Do save bonuses stack from multiple magic items in AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, saving-throw, dnd-adventurers-league, stacking

I play in Adventurers League and have a character that has a +1 Ring of Protection, which gives +1 to AC and saves. I also have a Stone of Good Luck which gives a +1 to saves and ability checks.

If I equip both items and my base Dex save is +4, would it become +6 due to receiving both bonuses, or +5 with just one? I can't find much in the PHB or Google to answer this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The bonuses stack: they are not coming from the same magical source.

> Yes. In general, bonuses stack<sup>1</sup> ... *J. Crawford, Sage Advice*

See the Caveat below for making sure that you discuss this with your DM before the session begins.

#### To help make your case ...

They are two different magical effects from two different items.  There is no text in either description that indicates that they would not stack.  What would not stack is two RoP +1.

DMG p. 138

> A creature can't attune to more than one copy of an item.  For example, a creature can't attune to more than one ring of protection at a time.

The *stone of good luck* helps with ability checks and saving throws, while the *Ring of Protection* helps with AC and saving throws.  They are not identical items.  As long as you have no more than three items attuned, and these two are among them, the rules do not preclude them stacking.

*Combining magical effects* is covered in the PHB (p. 205).  Since each item is different, though they both provide beneficial effects, they should both continue to work.

#### A Ruling From J. Crawford<sup>1</sup>

[From the Sage Advice compendium.](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf) (This is posted on the WoTC site.  Unless the AL expressly rejects Sage Advice, it should cover your situation.  (Page 16, Sage Advice, Version 1.14, @2016 Wizards of the Coast LLC.)

**Do the AC bonuses from a ring of protection and bracers of defense stack**?

> Yes. In general, bonuses stack, unless they’re from the same spell
> (see “Combining Magical Effects” in the Player’s Handbook, p. 205).
> You also can’t benefit from more than one ring of protection, for
> instance, since you can’t attune to more than one copy of an item at a
> time.

---

#### Caveat!  Discuss it with your DM before the session begins!

> Whether or not any given Dungeon Master chooses to utilize Sage Advice as a  resource for rules adjudication in D&D Adventurers League play is at the discretion of each individual DM. (A.L. FAQ) (Credit to @Miniman for catching this).

Comment: Thank you very much! The next question would then be since the DMG is not allowed in AL is this rule still applicable? Or is there something in the PHB that clarifies this?

Comment: @CharlieM See my point on the Sage Advice Ruling

Comment: @CharlieM I think you're conflating some things: the DMG certainly is allowed in AL, since it contains (among other things) descriptions of most of the magic items given out and it contains tables GMs are occasionally required to roll on. What's not allowed is for *players* to choose *player options* (death domain, &c.) in the DMG, or for GMs to use variant rules (disarm, &c.) that are in the DMG.

Comment: From what I have been told by people who organize conventions and what have you. The DMG is not usable by players. A good example of this is the simple "disarm" maneuver, can not be used by players. So you have to be a fighter to disarm. I tried this maneuver and had multiple long time DM's tell me the same thing at once.... was really embarrassing actually lol.

Comment: @CharlieM I understand that that particular implementation of Disarm is up to the DM as to whether or not he includes it as a rule, since it's only an option the DMG provides, but that's still surprising to me that they don't let you try to disarm at all; does AL not allow DM-improvised contests? Because that's a mechanic that the *PHB* encourages (p.195), and is basically how the DMG's implementation of Disarm works.

Comment: It's like i said earlier, the DMG is not admissible in AL. I don't understand it either but that's what i've been told by credible sources. I am not sure how the item reference as you've pointed out works. I just know the rulings in the DMG are definitely a no go. Now that i think about i think i remember him saying the DMG was not referenceable by players only. That would make more sense.

Comment: Disarming is a variant rule in the DMG. So is flanking. However, players don't choose the rules; the DM does. This does not inherently mean "the DMG is not admissible in AL".

Comment: @V2Blast Hopefully, that little point of confusion between the player and the DM has since been cleared up. (I admit I scratched my head a bit on how that came across ...)

Answer (score 13):

### The bonuses stack, and are balanced by attunement

As you say, there are no rules against stacking the bonuses of magic items. Indeed, effects that could be stacked in previous editions are now carefully worded to prevent stacking (such as Mage Armor).

Stacking problems are balanced by the attunement requirement (DMG 138-9). Both the Ring of Protection and the Stone of Good Luck require attunement, and you can only attune to 3 items at a time. This means that you're spending 2 of your 3 magic item slots to get your +2 bonus. Depending on your level and your DM, this might be worthwhile, or it might be a waste of attunement slots.

Additionally, note that the DMG explicitly forbids attuning to two copies of the same magic item, so you can't attune to two Stones of Good Luck to double your bonus.

Comment: I've added the DMG page numbers to the answer.